# Why can I move things to /dev/null despite it being a pseudo-device represented by a file?

Tags: linux

I always thought of `/dev/null` as a black hole, in the way that all data I send there will not be echoed back. However there's a problem with that definition. According to Wikipedia:

> /dev/null is a special file, not a
>   directory, so one cannot move files
>   into it with the Unix mv command.

So following this definition, why can I `mv` stuff there?
For example, I can easily do:

```
# touch oi
# mv oi /dev/null
```

What's going on there?

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: It does not work for me. What OS do you use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you'll try to move anything to /dev/null under a plain user (not root), you will get a `Permission denied` error because `mv something /dev/null` is actually trying to delete `/dev/null` and then move `something` to what `/dev/null` was.

If you will try to do it under root, it **will** delete `/dev/null` (and then move the file provided by you in it's place)! You can restore it by rebooting or typing the following in a root shell (on Linux): `mknod /dev/null c 1 3; chmod a+w /dev/null` or in BSD: `mknod /dev/null c 3 2; chmod a+w /dev/null`.

Comment: The device numbers will vary drastically from OS to OS: the pair 1,3 works on linux, but not on bsd-unixes.

Comment: edited accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

When you do this:

```
# mv oi /dev/null
```

You are actually doing the equivalent of the following

```
# rm /dev/null
# mv oi /dev/null
```

Comment: I think thats the solution, since its overwrite the node

Answer (score 3):

You can't

```
# uname -sr
Linux 2.6.32-ARCH
# touch a
# mv a /dev/null
mv: inter-device move failed: `a' to `/dev/null'; unable to remove target: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/null` is a character special file, which means that it is a contentless file that is marked as being able to source and sink byte streams to it.  What happens to those streams is determined by their device numbers.  On my BSD system at the moment:

```
crw-rw-rw-   1 root  wheel    3,   2 Jan 25 14:57 /dev/null
```

the device numbers are 3,2 (the major number is 3, minor number is 2).  I can create other `/dev/null` like files using `mknod /dev/nil c 3 2`, where the c means I want a character special file, but on BSD systems, the device number pair is dynamically created and might not be the same next boot.

To see how these facts apply in practice:

```
sh-2.05b# mknod /dev/nil c 3 2
sh-2.05b# ls -l /dev/nil
crw-r--r--   1 root  wheel    3,   2 Jan 25 15:14 /dev/nil
sh-2.05b# echo abc > /dev/nil
sh-2.05b# cat < /dev/nil
sh-2.05b#
```

Linux uses the major-minor pair 1,3, so `mknod /dev/null c 1 3` will recreate your file there.

Character special files are like most other files in many respects, and can be deleted if you have the permissions.  Using `mv` on a device file is just the same as if you moved a regular file, which will mean that you get a completely new file, which you can tell by looking at the inodes.  For example (Mac OS this time, but all *nixes will behave the same here):

```
helen:tmp cas$ touch abc def
helen:tmp cas$ ls -i1
3775141 abc
3775142 def
helen:tmp cas$ mv abc def
helen:tmp cas$ ls -i1
3775141 def
helen:tmp cas$ echo clobber > def
helen:tmp cas$ ls -i1
3775141 def
```

See how the inode associated with the filename `def` changed after I used `mv`, with the old file simply being deleted, but when I wrote the output of `echo` to the file named `def`, the inode remained the same.  So your `mv` will either fail, likely if you are not root, or delete the file and put a new file under path `/dev/null`, which is not what this character special is for.

Comment: You can use `cp -R /dev/null /some/other/null`. This is POSIX-compliant (http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/cp.1.asp) so it will work on virtually any Unix.

Comment: @whitequark: edited, and I've put in an explanation of the difference between what mv and clobbering do.

Answer (score 0):

Why `mv` a file to `/dev/null` (even if it's possible) when you could simply delete it?

Surely, `/dev/null` is more useful *and is intended* as a destination for output data?

Answer (score 0):

/dev/null is like a black hole and/or an empty file. terrific! You can put anything in here and get nothing from there.

Answer (score 0):

Shell Scripting is a common use:

`cat somefile >/dev/null 2>&1`

Sometimes you don't want to see/show errors etc.