# moving files to /dev/null ... is this complete deletion of data?

Tags: linux, data-recovery

this is a more academical then practical question (even though there may be practical implications).

can you recover a file that has been moved to /dev/null. In other words ... is the inode still alive?
If not this would be the perfect way to delete data in a privacy conforming way.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/100273/why-can-i-move-things-to-dev-null-despite-it-being-a-pseudo-device-represented also https://askubuntu.com/questions/435866/why-is-moving-directories-to-dev-null-dangerous and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117960/mv-a-file-to-dev-null-breaks-dev-null

Comment: If `/dev/null` were a valid filesystem (it isn't) then I might expect something to happen but you cant just move a file *into* that device. There is nothing to move it into and the command makes little logical sense. The dupe pretty much explains what would happen if you tried.

Comment: Even if it would be possible to move the file (which it isn't), the source disk drive would still have residuals of the file there, so it wouldn't be "better" or "more secure" than `rm`.

Comment: Why do this locally when there is /dev/null in the cloud  :) https://devnull-as-a-service.com/

Comment: thx, that help with the understanding